# What might be stopping this Contextualised Filter work in Block (please)?

Tags: 7, views, blocks

I am stuck making a contextualised filter in Block View (and I guess if I knew my question, I would also know my answer).

The view comprises

1. A set of images which I can see in the View before I set up the Contextualised View with their tags
2. Relationship with Content: Taxonomy terms on node, choose the correct Taxonomy, and check required
3. Under Contextual Filters, Taxonomy:name
4. Default View
5. Raw value from Url
6. Position is tricky  .. the path alias is albums/[node:title] but this is a multilingual site so en/albums/[node:title] (I have tried positions 1,2, 3)
7. Check Specific Validation Criteria
8. Validator:Taxonomy
9. Check correct taxonomy
10. Term Name
11. Tested check/unchecked spaces to hyphen
    Additional information
    The tag is input exactly as the [node:title]
    If the [node:title] is Barking Dogs, then that is the tag. So the [node:title] is changed by Drupal to barking-dogs and so is the tag.  But the name of the tag is not.  The name of the tag remain Barking Dogs.
    Results
12. When I put a tag name into the preview query, I get the correct results
    a.  For one word tags
    b.  When I type the phrase with space e.g. The Funniest Cat
13. When I type the shortened phrase, i.e., funniest-cat, I get no results. Checking the transform spaces into hyphens doesn’t help.
14. When I use the path alias /albums/[node:title], I get the title, such as The Funniest Cat, but no Block.
15. The Block itself works – If I request a summary when validation fails, that is displayed.  But no contextualised filter.

I am out of ideas. If anyone can spot where I have gone wrong, I’d be grateful.  Or have an idea how to test, as grateful.
Thanks.
Jo

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer - a logical issue rather than a question of using the controls.

The key was to reverse the order of bringing in content.  Set the main content-type as galleries, then use an entity relationship (set that up first) on Relationship to bring in fields from images and sort on them.

With this procedure, Views can use a Contextual filter for the Galleries. I will wirtie it out more fully on my blog.